# Free John the Ripper Dictionary Install

Tags: passwords, linux, password-cracking

What can I download a real free dictionary to use with John the Ripper? And where do I install the dictionary?

Comment: jtr comes with a real dictionary - there are many others available online - how you install them is found in the jtr documentation

Comment: Google around for wordlists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This link provides download for various password dictionaries:
https://wiki.skullsecurity.org/Passwords

This include
- `500-worst-passwords`
- `rockyou`
- `phpbb`
- `conflicker`
- and more!

You can find hundrets of these via a simple google search

You can use these files with the `--wordlist` parameter (assuming you are using command line).
See the [John documentation](http://www.openwall.com/john/doc/) for more information for how to use John.

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Jonas - the question was closed as off topic 15 minutes ago. Please don't keep adding more info to your answer.